# Viewing notes from an old iPod touch 4th generation.

Tags: ipod-touch

I had a 4th generation iPod touch and lost it over a year ago after I received a fifth generation. Now I would like to at least view the notes I had written on my old iPod but I don't have a gmail connected to it or anything that I know of that can allow me to do this. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible unless a) you already had your notes set to sync to your iCloud account before losing the device - and then only if some Nice Guy Greg turns it on and connects it to the Internet but doesn't try to unlock or wipe it - or b) you find it. As I understand it you can only enable any kind of iCloud sync from the device itself.
Sorry, but you appear to be out of luck.